# Renaming files with similar pattern

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have some video files and some subtitle files. There is a common part in the name of each of them, for example `*E05*.srt` and `*E05*.mkv`.

I'd like to rename each video file to match its subtitle, without `.srt` of curse.

Can you think of any script for that?

I guess it should be something like this:

```
Ls *.mkv | ren -path {$_.fullname} -newname { ls -path { "new folder/*" + $_.basename + "*.srt" } | select name }
```

I don't know!

That second `ls` doesn't have any problem, and will give me the subtitle, if I run it alone and without `ren`.

[I can't think of any better title for this post, I'll be thankful if someone can edit it.]

Comment: Can you post some example filenames? Is the overlapping bit always an E followed by two digits? Is it always in the same position within the filenames?  Are there any dashes or spaces to work with?

Comment: I should note that the second `ls` that I've written does the job. But this is an example: `BA S03 E01.mkv` and the subtitle: `BA S03 E01 - Some Episode Name.srt`. And I want the `mkv` file to be: `BA S03 E01 - Some Episode Name.mkv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all subtitle files begin with the basename of their respective video file something like this should work:

```psh
Get-ChildItem '*.mkv' | % {
  $newname = Get-Item ($_.BaseName + '*.srt') | select -First 1 -Expand BaseName
  if ($newname) { Rename-Item $_ "$newname.mkv" }
}
```

`select` is an alias for [`Select-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849895.aspx), which allows you to select particular properties of the input object(s). That will still leave you with an object, though, just with a specific set of properties (even if it's just one). However, in some situations you'll want just the value of a property instead of an object with that property. That's what the `-ExpandProperty` parameter (`-Expand` for short) is for. It expands the given property to its value, in this case the basename string.

Demonstration:

```
PS C:\> Get-Item .\test.txt

    Directory: C:\

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        13.06.2015     22:54        633 test.txt

PS C:\> Get-Item .\test.txt | Select-Object BaseName

BaseName
--------
test

PS C:\> Get-Item .\test.txt | Select-Object -ExpandProperty BaseName
test
```

Comment: Thanks Ansgar, I did the job. Can you please explain it? I don't really get that `select` and `expand` parts.